# Not getting output from function called by pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to learn pthreads as part of my C module for university. I have created a small bit of code to just verify that the pthreads are being created and it returning some data. **Please ignore all comments in the program. They are random notes to remind me of things.**

This program compiles. But does not produce any output (in this case tid & i). what I am expecting, is that when I throw it a command line argument. It is used for number of threads.

see below for the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
//struct

    struct threadArgs{
    int start;
    int finish;
};

// first part - create a function that takes two arguments. 

void *threadMain(void *p){
int i,c;
struct threadArgs *pargs = p;
// variables here for leibniz
int nstart=pargs->start, nfinish=pargs->finish; 
pthread_t tid = pthread_self(); //The pthread_self() function returns the ID of the calling thread

// i++ is slower than ++i. The difference is in order of operations. i++ copies and increases then throws away. ++i returns the value, and then increments it.
for(i=nstart; i<=nfinish; i++)
  { 
    for(c=2; c<=i-1; c++)
    {
      if ( i%c==0 )
        break;
    }
    if ( c==i )
      printf("Thread %ld : %d\n",tid, i);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int numThreads = 0;
  int i;
  pthread_t thrID[100];
  struct threadArgs targs[100];

  if ( argc > 1 ) {
    numThreads = atoi(argv[1]); 
  }
  if (numThreads > 0 && numThreads <= 100){
    int chunksize = 10000/numThreads ;
    for (i=0; i < numThreads; i++){
      targs[i].start = i * chunksize;
      targs[i].finish = (i * chunksize) + chunksize;
      pthread_create(&thrID[i], NULL, threadMain, &targs[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i < numThreads; i++){
      pthread_join(thrID[i], NULL);
    }
  }
}
```

The output seen from this... well there isn't one. The program just finishes.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any glaring errors. There's a lot of hoops `threadMain` needs to jump thru before it reaches your `printf`, I'm guessing all those conditions aren't satisfied. Start with one thread and step thru with a debugger to find out where your expectations and reality differ.

Comment: Have you printed the values for `nstart` and `nfinish` (along with TID) at the start of `threadMain()`? The code looks as if it is hunting prime numbers in the range 0..10,000, with each thread working in a given sub-range of that.  There are better ways to do that than the one chosed.  Are you dividing by zero?  That'll kill things!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this is a great point. Something I didn't notice. I'll take a look at it.
oddly it's worked as soon as I added the following:
'''
  printf("nstart");
  printf("nfinish");
  printf("TID");

Comment: Portability Note: The POSIX standard leaves the type of `pthread_t` to the discretion of the implementers.  On Linux, it is an integer type; on macOS, it is a pointer to a structure.  If your code is to work across both, it is probably best to convert to the `uintptr_t` type (from `<inttypes.h>` — or `<stdint.h> but you need other info from `<inttypes.h>`) and then print using an appropriate format: `PRIXPTR` or `PRIuPTR` or `PRIdPTR` depending on your preferences.  (I happen to work on a Mac as much as on Linux.)

Comment: The code works for me.  I called it `pth89.c` and compiled a hacked version of your code (fixing the TID printing, printing the control data at the start of the thread function, making the thread function `static` to satisfy my default compilation options), and running `./pth89 1` or `./pth89 2`, it works correctly.  If you run just `./pth89`, it emits nothing.  You should default to one thread rather than zero, or you should report the problem.  You should reject more than one argument with a usage message too (`if (argc != 2) { fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s threads\n", argv[0]; exit(1); }`).